# Firestore Rules for a user to create and edit his data only

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am new to firebase and and I finished building a react.js sire where the user fills a form which is saved under a sub collection called drivers, then the document of the user in users sub collection gets edited to show that he already filled the form before.
now I want to make a rule so that the user can only create forms and update his own form if needed in the future, and read his own form only

my firebase structure looks like this

```
users:
    autoId{
        uid,
        id,
        filledForm,
    }

drivers:
    id{
       idNumber,
    }
```

now the id and idNumber fields in users and drivers are the same value, and the id which is the name of the doc in drivers is also the same id , now I am trying to make a firebase rule where only the user with the same id could create abd edit his data in both drivers and users how can I achieve this?
here is what I have reached

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /drivers/{driver} {
      allow read,create,update: if isLoggedIn() && request.resource.data.idNumber == request.auth.token.id;

    }
    match /users/{user} {
      allow read,create,update: if isLoggedIn() && request.resource.data.id == request.auth.token.id;

    }
  }
  
    function  isLoggedIn(){
    return request.auth != null;
  }
  
  
}
```

Comment: Are the rules you shared not working for you? If so, can you show the (minimum) code you tried against these rules that didn't do what you expected, and what the result was you got?

Comment: this is the minimum i tried only the allow all requests before certain date works for now, I also tried to check the uid of the user against the doc uid but no change
every thing gets denied

Comment: OK, so you expect certain code to get rejected by these rules, but that is not happening? If so, can you edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show the code that is not doing what you expect against these rules? It might also help to know *where* that code runs.

Comment: there is stuff that should get rejected and stuff to get accepted but both gets rejected nothing goes through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your path users/{user}, {user}, is actually the document Id. If you have set the authentication token ID as the users document ID you can use that to check against the request auth token id.

Comment: the auth.token.id is the id field under the user document that is comming from the current user requesting the edit correct?

Comment: Not exactly. The request.auth.token.id is the firebase authentication id token that is given to that user, unrelated to firestore. This is why you are able to match that token to the users document ID, provided that you have saved the users documentID as their auth ID.

Comment: @Bahaeldin0 has this solution solved your problem?